Scheduled Task running powershell script randomly returned code 4294901760 (0xFFFF0000)
I have a pair of scheduled tasks that execute a powershell scripts running on a server. Both have been running for months without any issues and the scripts have not been changed.
Today for whatever reason the tasks showed as completing successfully but returned the code "0xFFFF0000 (4294901760). Its only happened one time (so far).
Manually running the scheduled tasks doesn't trigger the issue again but I'm worried it might later.
Can't find anything related to task scheduler and that error code.
Edit:
Added the scripts. Also important to note: Both scripts generate/write to log files, but no logging was done when the error occurred. Script 2 would run for an hour if it didn't find any files, but the scheduled task stopped within a second.
Script 1:
Robocopy D:\Folder "\\contoso.com\files\department\folder\a subfolder" /LOG:C:\folder\robocopy.log /XX /R:10 /W:10 /E

Script 2:
net use i: "\\192.168.1.1\a folder\subfolder" 
 
$d = "\\192.168.1.1\a folder\subfolder"
$e = "C:\folder\subfolder"
$log = "C:\folder\logfile.txt"
$start = get-date -format 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'
"$start Script process started" | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append
 
for ($a=0; $a -lt 60; $a++){
    $files=get-childitem $d
    if(($files).count){
        set-location $d
        $time= get-date -format 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'
        "$time Files found" | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append
        foreach($file in $files){
            Move-Item $file $e
            "$time Moved " + $d + "\$file to $e" | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append
        }
    }
    start-sleep 60
}
net use i: /del /y
$end = get-date -format 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'
 
"$end Script process ended" | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append
"----------------------------------" | Out-File -FilePath $log -Append
exit


Isn't it the script returning that error code, not the task scheduler itself? If that's the case then this question is unanswerable as-is since we have no info on the script in question

If thats the case then I fail to understand why the scripts have worked without issue for months, only to suddenly return this code now. And only one time. When I reran the scripts they worked without issue. One it just a single line robocopy command.

You might just need to add exit code explicitly at the end of the script. I vaguely recall having to do that with a simple Robocopy command script once too. Otherwise, show what line of logic it is too.

@JoamLopLop2 do you think it is more likely that the Task Scheduler that is developed by Microsoft has a bug, or that your script has a bug? It could be a "normal" but infrequent condition, e.g. if you're copying over a network, and there's a network issue, or the shared drive at the destination is not available due to a restart for an update

Honestly given its Microsoft, that's not a high bar anymore. Regardless, I've added a sanitized version of the scripts. Its also worth noting that both perform logging and no logging occurred when the scheduled task ran and returned this error code.
